# dispatch() from inside child route causes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

My Parent.js is split into child components using react-router-dom's Route like so:

**Parent.js**

```
return (
     <div>
       <Route
          path={"/community/" +  data.community.slug + "/" + props.match.params.channel}
          component={() => <Child {...props} />}
       />
       <Route path={etc...}/>
       <Route path={etc...}/>
     </div>
)
```

When a child is loaded (basically, when the url matches the Route's `path` (eg. /community/cars/repairs)) I gotta call an endpoint, get some data and save it in the store by calling `dispatch()` like so:

**Child.js**

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch({ type: 'SAVE_DATA', payload: [{...}] });
},[props.match.params.channel]) // trying to call it when the channel portion of the url changes
```

The problem is that the `dispatch` forces Parent.js to re-render itself which invokes the return() portion with `<Route>`'s in it and the loop begins.

How do I actually make it work properly?

**Update / Solution to my case**

Basically it works just fine if you call the route like so:

```
<Route path={"/community/" +  data.community.slug + "/" + props.match.params.channel} render={(routerProps)=> {
    return <Child {...props} community={data.community}/>
}} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using a callback method to the `component` prop of Route which recreates the component on each re-render of your Parent component and hence causing the child component to re-mount again which causes its `useEffect` to be called

You should simply pass the component name to `component` prop or use the `render` prop

```
 <Route
      path={"/community/" +  data.community.slug + "/" + props.match.params.channel}
      component={Child}
   />
```

or

```
<Route
      path={"/community/" +  data.community.slug + "/" + props.match.params.channel}
      render={(routerProps) => <Child {...routerProps} {...props} />}
   />
```

Comment: It doesn't trigger the loop if I dont pass {...props} at all. However something like this <Child {...routerProps} {...props} /> would set things on fire:(


I can just go with the first open without using the render, just <Router component={Child}/> but in that case how would I pass the data (slug, channel)?

Comment: Does the second example not work for you? Because I don't think there should be an issue by  using render prop and passing on the props by speading them considering that you are only watching on props.match.params.channel apart from the fact that other match params to Child might be overwritten. If thats the case, you must consider passing slug and channel directly instead of passing all the props to child

Comment: Actually it does after I tweaked it a bit (updated the question). Like actually return the component inside the render() part. Appreciate the assist!